# how to store and retrive array data from mysql by match (string to array AND array to array) i have problem in fetching data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, types, store

Store db as comma separated string and i want to retrieve data from a string separated by commas.

https://code.sololearn.com/wKW8F3caReUY/?ref=app

is this code work properly or not bcz it is not showing me the required results

//$userData['city'] = 27
//cities in db are saved as 12,33,9,2,1,27,31

```
    //$userData['hobbies'] = 3,24
    //hobbies in db have values as 3,24,17,31

    // how to i match these records/arrays by my sql db records

    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM users_stats WHERE 
    type = '1'
    AND
    (
        ".in_array( $userData['city'] ,  explode(",", "'cities'") )."
        OR
        cities IN('all','pak')
    )
    AND
    (
        time = ".$currentTime." OR time = 'all'
    )
    AND
    (
        ".((array_intersect( explode(",",$userData['hobbies']) , explode(",", "'hobbies'")) != null)?1:0)."
    )
    ";
```

Comment: I don't see a prepared statement being used.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 0):

you had confused the seperate environment.
PHP has it's own environment.
Database has it's own environment.

the basic process to get data from sql:
`build sql query text` ->  `send to database server` -> `parse the sql text,execute sql query` -> `return data back to php`

in your php code

```php
".in_array( $userData['city'] ,  explode(",", "'cities'") )."
```

the sql you build,you want explode the column `cities` in database,but at that moment the sql not execute yet,it seems you want to execute php in database environment.
`explode` is a php function,I guess you know that,and at this moment `cities` is just a string,not a database column which contain data in it.
after php execute the string will parse to  (which is `false`).

for the solution,there is no easy way to operation array in mysql(other database may operation array),so the simple way to do is get the `cities` column back to php,and `foreach` to filter the data you want